# Can Kinect v1 body detection work with more than 2 people?

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I have a question about Kinect v1.

The spec says it can detect up to two people with a skeleton. I have a project to detect body position of more than two people.

If I place a Kinect at a high position, is it possible to detect a man behind another person? Like three people at first row, and three people at second row. In the end, I just need the position of every person. I need the position of every person for detecting where a slot was empty. Is that possible with Kinect v1?

Answer (score 2):

Kinect v1 can track 6 players simultaneously (with a skeleton body position), but it can only provide full-body skeletal tracking for 2 players at a time. For your scenario, you should be able to use the skeleton body position for 6 players as it does not sound like you need full skeletal tracking.

(If you need full skeletal tracking for 6 players, novel approaches exist, such as cycling through all tracked skeletons. See "spinning skeletons" at 28min 35sec of this [GDC Talk: Augmented Imagination: Exploiting Kinect for Double Fine Happy Action Theater](https://www.gdcvault.com/play/1017901/Augmented-Imagination-Exploiting-Kinect-for).)

As long as you can fit 6 players into the Kinect's field of view, you should be able to track them all. If the Kinect is too high and the angle is too extreme, skeletal tracking may not work as well. I suggest you test it out yourself to see if it's feasible - place the Kinect high enough to cover the entire area, and then test using sample apps to see if you are able to be detected. If that works, test it with 6 people.

Answer (score 1):

In Kinect's version 1 as @sonny responded, there's no possibility of doing it. But using Machine Learning or Deep Learning approaches it's quite possible to detect a person among others in the picture.